# Sort the Interval in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, intervals

rigt now I'm having this list of Interval

```
test = ['(0.556, 1.389]', '(0.192, 0.386]', '(0.386, 0.556]', '(-0.759, -0.401]', '(-0.401, -0.064]', '(-0.064, 0.192]', '(-1.34, -0.759]']
```

I want to sort them into the correct order, I have tried these code:

```
test.sort()
sorted(test, key=lambda l:l[0])
```

However the results are not correct:

```
test = ['(-0.064, 0.192]', '(-0.401, -0.064]', '(-0.759, -0.401]', '(-1.34, -0.759]', '(0.192, 0.386]', '(0.386, 0.556]', '(0.556, 1.389]']
```

I just to to have a list that are sorted in order, like this:

```
test = ['(-1.34, -0.759]', '(-0.759, -0.401]', '(-0.401, -0.064]', '(-0.064, 0.192]', '(0.192, 0.386]', '(0.386, 0.556]', '(0.556, 1.389]']
```

Comment: Your list is a list of strings, I guess you first need to convert these into floats....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your list elements are strings. One way to solve your problem would be to convert them to tuples and sort the list of tuples afterwards:

```
import ast

test = ['(0.556, 1.389]', '(0.192, 0.386]', '(0.386, 0.556]', '(-0.759, -0.401]', '(-0.401, -0.064]', '(-0.064, 0.192]', '(-1.34, -0.759]']

new_list = []

for x in test:
    a = x.replace(']', ')')
    b = ast.literal_eval(a)
    new_list.append(b)

new_list = sorted(new_list, key=lambda l:l[0])
print(new_list)
# [(-1.34, -0.759), (-0.759, -0.401), (-0.401, -0.064), (-0.064, 0.192), (0.192, 0.386), (0.386, 0.556), (0.556, 1.389)]
```

This snippet takes your list, replaces the `]` at the end of every string with an `)` and then makes use of the `ast` library (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)) to turn the strings with `literal_eval` into actual tuples and append them to a new list.
Subsequently, it applies `sorted` as you proposed in your question.